# How to use http only cookie with django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, cookie-httponly

I read about some of the issues related to storing jwt token in local storage that's why I am trying to store token in http-only cookie. I am using following approach.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
import jwt
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import status

class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        # dummy user authentication
        if email == 'email' and password == 'password':
            encoded = jwt.encode(
                {'email': email}, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

            response = Response()
            response.set_cookie(key='token', value=encoded, httponly=True)
            response.data = {
                'user': email,
            }
            return response
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'wrong credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

> Question 1: Is this a right approach to set httponly cookie using django rest framework?

```
response = Response()
response.set_cookie(key='token', value=encoded, httponly=True)
response.data = {
    'user': email,
}
return response
```

After this every time when I am getting a request from the client (using React with axios) I am able to access the cookie using `request.COOKIES['token']` in django view. Using this I can write my own function for authentication but I don't think it is a perfect approach because generally, we pass token in Authorization headers which sets the `request.user` based on the token and if I use this approach I will not be unable to use postman for testing and django rest frameworks `IsAuthenticated` class also looks for `request.user and request.user.is_authenticated` for True value.

> Question 2: How to pass the token as an Authorization header from the client if the token is stored in httponly cookie?

Please help me. I am a bit confused with the workflow of http-only cookie because generally I used to store token in local storage and it was easier to retrieve the token and pass it from the frontend.

Comment: did you get a solution to this problem?

Comment: No yet, @ArkaGhosh

Comment: @ArkaGhosh you can follow this https://www.procoding.org/jwt-token-as-httponly-cookie-in-django/

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:**

Yes this is a good approach to set `httponly` flag cookie because
`httpOnly` cookies can't be accessed by `JavaScript`.
Without `httponly` flag cookie it vulnerable to `CSRF` attacks.

While `localStorage` is accessible through `javascript` (as opposed to `HttpOnly` cookies) and makes it vulnerable to `XSS` attacks.
So I think using `httponly cookies` + `CSRF` is the most secure way even in TokenAuthentication for storing tokens on client. However, this is not very well supported by `DRF` and other popular libraries that I've looked at.

**Answer 2:**

No, because you can not retrieve `httponly` cookie by using `javascript` from client side.It's big Advantage of `httponly` cookie.So this cookie only accessible through `http(s)` request.
Make sure `withCredentials` is `True` for both side.

I personally use `djangorestframework-simplejwt` package to set (`access token` + `CSRF` token) in `httponly` cookie and get by using `CustomAuthentication` class.  [**Check this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66248320/14131913)

Comment: What if you want to refresh token?