# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response' error on Django HttpOnly JWT solution

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf, csrf-token, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I currently have a Django setup that followed the guide below. Pretty much, it's a workaround that allows for HTTPOnly cookies to be used with Django Rest Framework JWT authentication. It worked fine in Django 3.2, but I'm attempting to upgrade to Django 4, and I'm now running into the error below

[How to store JWT tokens in HttpOnly cookies with DRF djangorestframework-simplejwt package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247988/how-to-store-jwt-tokens-in-httponly-cookies-with-drf-djangorestframework-simplej)

Error:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'
```

I'm still a bit new to Django and DRF, so I have no idea what could be going on.

Edit:

Apologies, forgot to add some details. The error is in the following code, on CSRFCheck():

```
   from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.authentication import CSRFCheck
from rest_framework import exceptions


def enforce_csrf(request):
    # Enforce CSRF validation.
    check = CSRFCheck()
    check.process_request(request)
    # populates request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'], which is used in process_view()
    reason = check.process_view(request, None, (), {})

    if reason:
        # CSRF failed, bail with explicit error message
        raise exceptions.PermissionDenied('CSRF Failed: %s' % reason)


class CustomAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        header = self.get_header(request)
        if header is None:
            raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE']) or None
        else:
            raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)
        if raw_token is None:
            return None
        validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
        enforce_csrf(request)
        return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
```

Traceback messages:
(Full error: jsfiddle.net/Luizram/t7u03cqy/1 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 55, in inner

```
        return inner

    else:

        @wraps(get_response)

        def inner(request):

            try:

                response = get_response(request) <- Line 55

 …

            except Exception as exc:

                response = response_for_exception(request, exc)

            return response

        return inner
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 197, in _get_response

```
        if response is None:

            wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)

            # If it is an asynchronous view, run it in a subthread.

            if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(wrapped_callback):

                wrapped_callback = async_to_sync(wrapped_callback)

            try:

                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) <- Line 197

 …

            except Exception as e:

                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

                if response is None:

                    raise

        # Complain if the view returned None (a common error).
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py, line 54, in wrapped_view

```
def csrf_exempt(view_func):

    """Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection."""

    # view_func.csrf_exempt = True would also work, but decorators are nicer

    # if they don't have side effects, so return a new function.

    def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):

        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) <- Line 54

 …

    wrapped_view.csrf_exempt = True

    return wraps(view_func)(wrapped_view)
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py, line 84, in view

```
            self = cls(**initkwargs)

            self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)

            if not hasattr(self, "request"):

                raise AttributeError(

                    "%s instance has no 'request' attribute. Did you override "

                    "setup() and forget to call super()?" % cls.__name__

                )

            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) <- Line 84

 …

        view.view_class = cls

        view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs

        # __name__ and __qualname__ are intentionally left unchanged as

        # view_class should be used to robustly determine the name of the view
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 509, in dispatch

```
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)

            else:

                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed

            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

        except Exception as exc:

            response = self.handle_exception(exc) <- Line 509

 …

        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)

        return self.response

    def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        """
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 469, in handle_exception

```
        exception_handler = self.get_exception_handler()

        context = self.get_exception_handler_context()

        response = exception_handler(exc, context)

        if response is None:

            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc) <- Line 469

 …

        response.exception = True

        return response

    def raise_uncaught_exception(self, exc):

        if settings.DEBUG:
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception

```
    def raise_uncaught_exception(self, exc):

        if settings.DEBUG:

            request = self.request

            renderer_format = getattr(request.accepted_renderer, 'format')

            use_plaintext_traceback = renderer_format not in ('html', 'api', 'admin')

            request.force_plaintext_errors(use_plaintext_traceback)

        raise exc <- Line 480

 …

    # Note: Views are made CSRF exempt from within `as_view` as to prevent

    # accidental removal of this exemption in cases where `dispatch` needs to

    # be overridden.

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        """
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 497, in dispatch

```
        self.args = args

        self.kwargs = kwargs

        request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)

        self.request = request

        self.headers = self.default_response_headers  # deprecate?

        try:

            self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs) <- Line 497

 …

            # Get the appropriate handler method

            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:

                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),

                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)

            else:
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 414, in initial

```
        request.accepted_renderer, request.accepted_media_type = neg

        # Determine the API version, if versioning is in use.

        version, scheme = self.determine_version(request, *args, **kwargs)

        request.version, request.versioning_scheme = version, scheme

        # Ensure that the incoming request is permitted

        self.perform_authentication(request) <- Line 414

 …

        self.check_permissions(request)

        self.check_throttles(request)

    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):

        """

        Returns the final response object.
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 324, in perform_authentication

```
        """

        Perform authentication on the incoming request.

        Note that if you override this and simply 'pass', then authentication

        will instead be performed lazily, the first time either

        `request.user` or `request.auth` is accessed.

        """

        request.user <- Line 324

 …

    def check_permissions(self, request):

        """

        Check if the request should be permitted.

        Raises an appropriate exception if the request is not permitted.

        """
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py, line 227, in user

```
    def user(self):

        """

        Returns the user associated with the current request, as authenticated

        by the authentication classes provided to the request.

        """

        if not hasattr(self, '_user'):

            with wrap_attributeerrors():

                self._authenticate() <- Line 227

 …

        return self._user

    @user.setter

    def user(self, value):

        """

        Sets the user on the current request. This is necessary to maintain
```

Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py, line 380, in _authenticate

```
    def _authenticate(self):

        """

        Attempt to authenticate the request using each authentication instance

        in turn.

        """

        for authenticator in self.authenticators:

            try:

                user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self) <- Line 380

 …

            except exceptions.APIException:

                self._not_authenticated()

                raise

            if user_auth_tuple is not None:

                self._authenticator = authenticator
```

Local vars
/django/users/authenticate.py, line 30, in authenticate

```
        if header is None:

            raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE']) or None

        else:

            raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)

        if raw_token is None:

            return None

        validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)

        enforce_csrf(request) <- Line 30

 …

        return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
```

Local vars
/django/users/authenticate.py, line 10, in enforce_csrf

```
from rest_framework.authentication import CSRFCheck

from rest_framework import exceptions

def enforce_csrf(request):

    # Enforce CSRF validation.

    check = CSRFCheck() <- Line 10

 …

    check.process_request(request)

    # populates request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'], which is used in process_view()

    reason = check.process_view(request, None, (), {})

    if reason:

        # CSRF failed, bail with explicit error message
```

Comment: Please include relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @ewong Sorry about that, I've added it

Comment: Please include the full error traceback message, not just the final line.

Comment: This is a little confusing.  Please just include the full traceback error as-is and your code as-is.

Comment: @ewong Sorry about that. The error is quite long. I've but the entire thing in a jsfiddle so it's human readable https://jsfiddle.net/Luizram/t7u03cqy/1/ I also added arrows with the line numbers it's mentioning in the post if that helps