# How to send JWT REFRESH TOKEN as http only cookie in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using **Django**(REST FrameWork, SimpleJWT) and **React** for my project. For autentication I am using **JWT** method.

According to some articles, storing and sending **REFRESH TOKEN** in **HttpOnly Cookie** is the a best and secure way. Since I am learning *WebDevelopment* I can't able to find any source to about it.

This is my **views.py**

```
class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            response = super().post(request)
        except InvalidToken:
            return Response({'Invalid or expired token'})
        refresh_token = RefreshToken.for_user(request.user)
        response.set_cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, httponly=True)
        return response

class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

class LogoutView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def post(self, request):
        refresh_token = request.data['refresh_token']
        token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
        token.blacklist()
        return Response({'Logout':'Successfullly'})
```

as you can i even tried to over write the post method in MyTokenObtainPairView.

This is my **urls.py**

```
    path('api/login/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair"),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="token_refresh"),
    path('api/register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name="auth_register"),
    path('api/logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
```

This is my settings.py

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=2),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',

    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=2),
}
```

I am expecting a way to store and send **REFRESH TOKEN** in **HttpOnly Cookie** to frontend when user logins or refresh it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find an answer in this thread:
[How to store JWT tokens in HttpOnly cookies with DRF djangorestframework-simplejwt package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247988/how-to-store-jwt-tokens-in-httponly-cookies-with-drf-djangorestframework-simplej)

[This GitHub comment](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/issues/71#issuecomment-762927394) also suggests a similar solution.